# Combine MLflow projects with docker-compose

Tags: machine-learning, docker-compose, pipeline, mlflow

I face the following situation:

We train our models within docker container, which is build by running a docker-compose file. I have implemented MLflow to work with docker-compose (by doing something similar to e.g. this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-mlflow-with-docker-compose-8059f16b6039), creating two more containers (one for the server and one for the postgresql backend).

However, the story doesn't end here. Our goal is to implement a full ML pipeline, which includes data creation, preprocessing steps and so on. I know, that ML projects is something which helps to create such pipeline. I have seen that it is designed to work with docker images (https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html), but I don't get it, how one could use it with docker-compose.

Could you help me in that by giving any tipps, guidelines, documentations, etc?

Or in general, any advice, how a full machine learning pipeline could be implemented using mlflow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You dont. Leave mlflow as it is. Your projects should be dockerized, so that you can run your python scripts without installing/configuring anything apart from docker run yourimage